# Can I change background color and/or key color of Android soft keyboard without custom IME

Tags: android, keyboard

For my new application, I would like to change the background color and key color on the soft keyboard to match the theme of my app.  Is this possible without creating a custom keyboard?

Also, if I were to create a custom keyboard/IME solely for styling purposes, would any custom keyboards used by users override the custom keyboard I developed for use with my app?